# Unable run run Flutter Application in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

My Flutter Application was working fine, but suddenly it started giving this gradle issue in android studio.

i tried removing .pub_cache folder as well, along with removing build folder inside my application but still facing this issue when i am opening my flutter application in android studio

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWwlY.png)

what is shared_preference_android here and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Install flutter on the disk your projects are on. If not copy your project on the disk your flutter is installed.

Comment: Do you know from which gradle file this task is from?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fixes to try before doing anything drastic:**

Try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`.

If that doesn't work, you can try upgrading your Flutter SDK (not sure if you'd want to) like so: `flutter upgrade`.

You can also run `flutter doctor` to see a list of possible issues with your code.

Comment: tried both, but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

- Try to run `./gradlew clean` and `./gradlew build` on `yourproject/android`.
- Try to run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` on `yourproject/lib` or try to use `flutter doctor` to see issues.

these two commands work properly to fix your machine bugs or your code bugs

Comment: tried, but still same issue